# TLS doesn't work with LoadBalancer backed Service in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, kops

I am trying to expose an application in my cluster by creating a service type as load balancer. The reason for this is that I want this app to have a separate channel for communication. I have a KOPS cluster. I want to use AWS's network load balancer so that it gets a static IP. When I create the Service with port 80 mapped to the port that the app is running on everything works but when I try to add port 443 it just times out.

Here is the configuration that works -

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: abc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
  labels:
    app: abc
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9050
  selector:
    app: abc
  type: LoadBalancer
```

As soon as I add TLS support in the config file and deploy it. The connection to the load balancer times out. How do I add TLS support to the load balancer?
I want to do it through the service and not through an ingress.
This is the configuration that doesn't work for me and when I paste the link in the browser, it times out.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: abc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: xxxxx
  labels:
    app: abc
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9050
  selector:
    app: abc
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tls & ssl termination

```
   apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: test-service
      annotations:
        # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
        # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:{region}:{user id}:certificate/{id}
        # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    spec:
      selector:
        app: test-pod
      ports:
      - name: http
        port: 80
        targetPort: 8080
      - name: https
        port: 443
        targetPort: 8080
      type: LoadBalancer
```

You can add the tls certficate in aws certificate manager and use the arn address of certificate to kubernetes service.

it's like in becked you can terminate the https connection and use the HTTP only.

you can also check this out : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-https-traffic-eks-acm/

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73297
```

EDIT :1

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

if not work please try adding this annotation as per your loadbalancer type.

Comment: This is what my question is. I have added all the configuration needed to add SSL termination but when I add that the TLS support I can't access the app. The TLS configuration doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AnshulTripathi which kubernetes version you are using ? in Kubernetes 1.8, you can't currently terminate TLS in the ELB without customizing the nginx config template.

Comment: @AnshulTripathi check edit 1 i have updated answer.

Comment: my Kube version is v1.10.12.

Comment: And I already have the config - service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"

Answer (score 0):

You can now deploy ingress using NLB and SSL termination (https in NLB > http in service). 
Finally found a solution that worked for me, you can try to deploy the following ingress.yaml (make sure to update your cert ARN under deployment section):

```
    ---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/default-backend-serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-backend
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    component: "controller"
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
data:
  server-snippet: |
    listen 8000;
    if ( $server_port = 80 ) {
       return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  ssl-redirect: "false"
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - "networking.k8s.io" # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - "networking.k8s.io" # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-ingress
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - "networking.k8s.io" # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - "networking.k8s.io" # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - ingress-controller-leader-nginx
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - create
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-ingress
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-ingress
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:##REPLACE WITH YOUR CERT ARN"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    component: "controller"
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: special
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    release: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  type: "LoadBalancer"
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/default-backend-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    component: "default-backend"
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-default-backend
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    release: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/component: default-backend
  type: "ClusterIP"
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  annotations:
    {}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
      release: nginx-ingress
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  strategy:
    {}
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
        release: nginx-ingress
        component: "controller"
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-default-backend
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
                drop:
                - ALL
                add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: special
              containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          resources:
            {}
      hostNetwork: false
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
---
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/default-backend-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.38.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/component: default-backend
  name: nginx-ingress-default-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
      release: nginx-ingress
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
        release: nginx-ingress
        app.kubernetes.io/component: default-backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-default-backend
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/defaultbackend-amd64:1.5"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 65534
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 0
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {}
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-backend
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Your annotation refers to `https` port

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"`

but your port is named `http`, change to `https`

```
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9050
```