# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS with Nginx Ingress Controller, AWS NLB and TLS certificate managed by AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, nlb

I've tried the following to get HTTP to redirect to HTTPS. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

`ingress-nginx` object:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:...
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: http
```

`my-ingress` object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
spec:
  tls:
   - hosts:
     - app.example.com
  rules:
  - host: app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

I get a `308 Permanent Redirect` on HTTP and HTTPS. I guess this makes sense as the NLB is performing the SSL termination and therefore forwarding HTTP to the Nginx service? I guess I would need to move the SSL termination from the NLB to the Nginx service?

Thanks

Comment: for each service you create NLB ? as service type if loadbalancer ? suppose you have 10 frontend exposed application you will create 10 NLB ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030504/8490256 for SSL termination.

Comment: Had the same issue with SSL termination at NLB and could solve it using only `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"`. Erase `force-ssl-redirect`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you do need to move the SSL termination to the ingress controller because I am having the same issue and I appear to be in a permanent redirect situation. The traffic comes into the NLB on 443 and is terminated and sends to the backend instances over port 80. The ingress sees the traffic on port 80 and redirects to https:// and thus begins the infinite loop.

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue, could you eloborate when you said move SSL termination to ingress controller.How to do that?

Comment: Is this supported now? [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/] It says `SSL termination will need to happen at the backend, since SSL termination on NLB for Kubernetes is not yet available.`

Comment: ssl termination is do work over k8s using ingress and nlb

Comment: you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030504/8490256

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**
There is no need to move SSL termination to nginx-ingress controller. You can still configure it to handle redirects.
IF using **HELM** installation of Nginx Ingress add the following configuration to values:

```
controller:
  service:
    targetPorts:
      http: tohttps
      https: http
```

**Longer version:**
There seems to be a difference of how nginx-ingress is installed and why some people face the issues like "SSL termination on NLB and getting 400 on Nginx" and this one with redirects.

Nginx repository suggests a couple of ways for deployment:

- static deployment for AWS - [LINK](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml)
- static deployment for AWS with TLS handling on NLB - [LINK](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/deploy/static/provider/aws/nlb-with-tls-termination/deploy.yaml)
- helm chart - [LINK](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx)

The AWS with TLS is the one that by default should solve the mentioned issues.
It has a different configuration for the Service object in terms of ports to handle offloaded https traffic:

```
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: tohttps
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
```

and has an additional configuration for handling https redirects.

```
  http-snippet: |
server {
  listen 2443;
  return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Generic deployment for AWS doesn't have the needed objects, so you need to tune the Service and Nginx config manually.